# Conectar aplicação Laravel no WSL2 com o banco de dados no Windows

Tags: mysql, laravel

Eu tenho uma aplicação laravel utilizando o WSL2 que executa normalmente. Tive um problema recente quando precisei conectar essa aplicação com o banco de dados que está instalado no Windows. Tentei conectar diversas vezes e sempre retorna o seguinte erro:

```
sqLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Acredito que o problema não está nas credenciais, como está no arquivo .env abaixo:

(as 3 últimas linhas são confidenciais :D)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=banco
DB_USERNAME=usuario
DB_PASSWORD=senha
```

Estou usando o MySQL Workbench para acessar os dados do banco e está funcionando corretamente. O mesmo acontece com a aplicação laravel, que funciona corretamente com exceção dessa conexão esse banco de dados no Windows. Ou seja, as aplicações funcionam corretamente, parece que apenas não estão conseguindo conversar.

Como faço essa aplicação Laravel no WSL2 se comunicar com o MySQL que foi instalado no Windows?

Comment: As configurações por acaso não estão em cache com outros dados? A porta que o Mysql está configurado no Windows é essa (3306) padrão mesmo?

Comment: Fala Marcos, em relação a porta do MySQL é essa mesmo! Vou ver essa questão do cache, para ver se é o problema aqui

Answer (score -3):

O problea e q vc esta tentando acessar um banco q esta dentro do wsl, quando vc coloca 127.0.0.1 isso e igual a localhost e o localhost esta dentro do wsl, quando vc tem um wsl vc cria uma maquina virtual dentro da sua maquina e isso faz com q ela tenha um ip difernte, se vc der o comando ipconfig vc vera q tera esta frase no terminal:

Adaptador de Rede sem Fio Wi-Fi: este e da sua maquina do windows
Adaptador Ethernet vEthernet (WSL): e esta e do wsl

vc tem q falar par ao laravel o ip da sua maquina do windows